# use CSS while sending html format mail using jsp

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, email

I've been working on jsp(spring, mvc model2) to send html format mail using jsp and javamail. Object message is the part where read by email receiver. I used basic html tags to decorate, but I would like to use CSS so that I can design it more. Is there any way to use css when I send mail using javamail?

Here is the mail sender controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mailSender", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String mailSender(@RequestParam(value = "mem_id", defaultValue = "") String mem_id,
        @RequestParam(value = "encrypt_no", defaultValue = "") String encrypt_no,
        @RequestParam(value = "occu_code", defaultValue = "0") int occu_code) throws AddressException, MessagingException {

    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    final String username = "gmailid"; 
    final String password = "gmailpw";  
    int port=465;       


    String recipient = mem_id;

    String subject = "mail title";  
     Object message  = 
             "<h2><strong>HOTEL NOMAD</strong></h2><br>"
            + "<h3>reset your pw<br><br>"
            + "http://127.0.0.1:8080/team/pwReset?encrypt_no="+encrypt_no+"&mem_id="+mem_id;


    Properties props = System.getProperties(); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", host); 


    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        String un=username;
        String pw=password;
        protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
            return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(un, pw); 
            } 
        });

    session.setDebug(true); //for debug


    Message mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);  
    mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress("ruthhere@naver.com")); 
    mimeMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient)); 
    mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
    mimeMessage.setText((String) message);
    mimeMessage.setContent(message, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
    Transport.send(mimeMessage); }

    System.out.println("an email has been sent");
    if(occu_code!=0) return "redirect:/pay_after?occu_code="+occu_code+"&mem_id="+occupation.getMem_id();
    return "redirect:/main";
}
```

Comment: Post the error/log.

Comment: @Al-KathiriKhalid There is no error/log, I just would like to know if there is any way to use css when I send mail using javamail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible way of doing it:

- You could attach the CSS file as an attachment and in HTML you can
  reference it using "cid:style.css"
- You could include the whole CSS
  script in body section of HTML file

Here is **the catch** either way some clients will work fine but for some it wont, even if you managed to get your attachments to work, due to security reasons major email providers block/strip attached css file/contents. I would suggested to avoid using css file try inline style.

```
<h2><span style="background-color: #ff0000;">Writing HTML Mail</span></h2>
```

Further Resource:

- Main: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/
- Specific: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/apidocs/org/apache/commons/mail/HtmlEmail.html

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You use mail-template. this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mail.html#mail-templates)